# Need to align li text to top of bullet icon AND keep it from wrapping under on the second line

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists

So I have large checkmark icons that I want to use as list bullets.
I need the text to align at the top of the bullet AND keep the text from wrapping underneath the other text while keeping a reasonable line height. Everything else I've found gives directions for one or the other, but not both together.

CSS

```
<style>
ul {
    list-style: inside;
    list-style-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/DRHniGK.png')
}
li {
    vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div style="width:940px;">
        <ul>
            <li>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH </li>
            <hr>
            <li>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH </li>
            <hr>
            <li>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH </li>
            <hr>
            <li>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH </li>
            <hr>
            <li>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gMh5W/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) your HTML is invalid. You cannot insert elements outside of list items. If you want more spacing, add padding or margins to your list items.

2) Use a CSS background, not `list-style-image`:

```
li {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/DRHniGK.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:3px 3px;
    padding-left:15px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

...then adjust the background position and the padding to suit your layout.

Comment: Do you mean the <hr>s? Those are really just for readability here, not included on my site.

Comment: You don't include any HTML tags for readability. You can insert white space  instead.